# Android: Show and pause GIF images

Tags: android, animated-gif

I know many people have already asked how to display GIF images in Android, but most answers have most problems:

- They use libraries that are now deprecated.
- They use libraries that don't allow pausing (and resuming) of the animation, which is something I would like to do.

What is the simplest way to do this at the moment?

Answer (score 1):

There is a good library to show GIF images in your app. [android-gif-drawable](https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable)

It features a very good usage both from XML and Java. Also it provides you with a very easy-to-use API.

Here is a list of methods you're likely interested in:

> `GifDrawable` implements an `Animatable` and `MediaPlayerControl` so you can use its methods and more:
>
> - `stop()` - stops the animation, can be called from any thread
> - `start()` - starts the animation, can be called from any thread
> - `isRunning()` - returns whether animation is currently running or not
> - `reset()` - rewinds the animation, does not restart stopped one
> - `setSpeed(float factor)` - sets new animation speed factor, eg. passing 2.0f will double the animation speed
> - `seekTo(int position)` - seeks animation (within current loop) to given position (in milliseconds)
> - `getDuration()` - returns duration of one loop of the animation
> - `getCurrentPosition()` - returns elapsed time from the beginning of a current loop of animation